# android webview

Tags: android, redirect, webview, load

HI all

I'm developing an application into that I want to redirect the current page to the next page after the webView has completely loading of the data.

How can I manage that?

Comment: can you state your question more clearly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a WebViewClient to the WebView which has a callback method when a page is finished loading like this:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    if(myFirstUrl.equals(url) {
        webView.loadUrl(mySecondUrl);
    }
}});
```

Comment: okk thank you but can i redirect it to any my local page? thank you in advance

Comment: Just put your local html files in the assets folder of your project and reference them by using an url which starts with "file:///android_asset/" e.g. file:///android_asset/index.html